# How to use webpack variable in jest unit test ( angular)?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, webpack, jestjs

I have this component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { getImageUrl } from '../../shared/get-image-url';

@Component({
  selector: 'ice-section-banner-invite-client',
  templateUrl: './section-banner-invite-client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./section-banner-invite-client.component.scss'],
})
export class IceSectionBannerInviteClient {
  public loading = false;

  public imageUrl = `url(${getImageUrl('assets/images/banner-criar-conta.png')})`;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.imageUrl);
  }

  public clickInviteClient(): void {
    window.open(`${document.location.origin}${'/br-iceberg/invitations'}`);
  }
}
```

The component uses this function:

```
export function getImageUrl(imageName: string) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-expect-error
  // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
  let publicPath: string = __webpack_public_path__;
  publicPath = publicPath.endsWith('/') ? publicPath.slice(0, -1) : publicPath;

  return `${publicPath}/${imageName}`;
}
```

Then, there is the test file for the component:

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { OnDashboardModule } from '@onviobr/dashboard';
import { TranslateTestingModule } from 'ngx-translate-testing';

import { IceSectionBannerInviteClient } from './section-banner-invite-client.component';

describe('IceSectionBannerInviteClient', () => {
  let component: IceSectionBannerInviteClient;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<IceSectionBannerInviteClient>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [IceSectionBannerInviteClient],
      imports: [
        OnDashboardModule,
        TranslateTestingModule.withTranslations({}),
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(IceSectionBannerInviteClient);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
IceSectionBannerInviteClient › should create

    ReferenceError: __webpack_public_path__ is not defined
```

How can I mock a value for `__webpack_public_path__` ?

I have tried:

- Using `providers: [{ provide: __webpack__public__path__, useValue: 'teste' }],` in spec file
- Using `process.env = Object.assign(process.env, { __webpack__public__path__: 'teste' });` in spec file
- Using `process.env.__webpack__public__path__ = 'teste';` in spec file
- Using `process.env = Object.assign(process.env, { __webpack__public__path__: 'teste' });` in jest.config.js
- Setting `globals: {__webpack__public__path__: 'value',}` in jest.config.js
- Using `jest: { setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/setup.js'] },` in jest.config.js with `process.env.__webpack__public__path__ = 'value';` inside `setup.js`

None of those works. And whenever I try using `process.env` it gives this error `Cannot find name 'process'.`, but I already have `"compilerOptions": { "types": ["node"] },` in my tsconfig file.

Can anybody help with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks, you have issue with `ReferenceError` since `__webpack_public_path__` is automatically set by Webpack at build time.

Since `Jest` is a test runner and not a build tool like Webpack, it does not provide access to the `__webpack_public_path__` variable, and I am not sure there is direct way to set or mock it within `Jest`.

Instead, you can mock your `getImageUrl` function if you only care about component creation in your test

Like

```js
jest.mock('../../shared/get-image-url', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('../../shared/get-image-url'),
  getImageUrl: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('mocked-image-url'),
}));

describe('IceSectionBannerInviteClient', () => {

  //previous code
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(IceSectionBannerInviteClient);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: That would actually help a lot, but I'm getting this error:

 `error TS2694: Namespace 'jest' has no exported member 'Mock'.

    33     (getImageUrl as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue('mocked-image-url');`

Comment: @BeatrizRachel not sure why jest has no exported interface `Mock` - it exists for ages. :)
Let's try another solution - see updated code.

Mock you function directly in `jest.mock`

Comment: Mocking the function directly in `jest.mock` is what worked here! Thank you.
And I really don't know why the `Mock` interface is not being recognized :/

Comment: Well, you can go to jest module and to see if `Mock` interface exists... Sometimes it can be resolved by downgrading / upgrading jest, but it's another issue)
Can you mark this answer as correct if it works for you, plz? :)